# upload a rails 4 app with capistrano to dreamhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, dreamhost

I am trying to deploy a rails 4 app to dream host using capistrano. everytime I run `cap deploy:cold` this is what I got,

> Stage not set, please call something such as cap production deploy,
>   where production is a stage you have defined.

Here it is my set up:

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'

set :application, "mywebsite.com" # Your application location on your server goes here

default_run_options[:pty] = true

set :repository,  "."
set :scm, :none
set :deploy_via, :copy

set :checkout, 'export'

set :user, 'user name' # Your username goes here
set :use_sudo, false
set :domain, 'mywebsite.com' # Your domain goes here
set :applicationdir, "/home/#{user}/#{application}"
set :deploy_to, applicationdir

role :web, domain                 
role :app, domain                          
role :db,  domain, :primary => true 


set :chmod755, "app config db lib public vendor script script/* public/disp*"

namespace :deploy do

  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end

end
```

Comment: any tips to upload a rails4 app fast and easy to dreamhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deploy using capistrano 3.x script, you need to specify `stage`. Try this:

```
cap production deploy:cold
```